# Front end user registration form

Tags: page-template, errors

I have created front side registration form is as under

```
            <?php
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Template Name: newForm-template

            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

            get_header(); ?>

            <div id="content" class="clearfix">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="column column-title">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'breadcrumb' ); ?>
                    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="title-header">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- end .column-title -->

                <div class="column column-narrow">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
                </div><!-- end .column-narrow -->

                <div class="column column-content single">

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                    comments_template(); ?>

                </div><!-- end .column-content -->

                <div class="column column-narrow column-last">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ); ?>
                </div><!-- end .column-narrow -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                            <!-- Form to be display on user side  -->
                    <?php
                                        global $post;
                                        // clear the cashe data meance not repeat a post, when refresh the page

                                        if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

                                            global $wpdb;   // to connect a database 


                                            //store array arg in database
                                             $custompost = array('post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_author' => $user_ID,
                                                            'ping_status' => get_option('default_ping_status'), 'post_parent' => 0,
                                                            'menu_order' => 0,'post_content_filtered' => '', 'post_excerpt' => '', 'import_id' => 0,
                                                            'post_content' => $_POST['content'], 'post_title' => $_POST['contactTitle']);

                                                 //var_dump($id);

                                            $postId = wp_insert_post($custompost);
                        ?>



                <div id="postbox">
                            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post" >
                            <table border="0">  
                            <tr>
                                    <td><h2>Registration Form</h2></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr><td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="name" />
                                </td></tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="designation">Designation/Class:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="designation" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="designation" /></td>
                                <td><label for="sex">Sex:</label>               
                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
                                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="organization">Organization:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="organization" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="organization" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="postaladdress">Postal Address</label></td>
                                <td><textarea id="postaladdress" tabindex="3" name="postaladdress" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="telephoneoffice">Telephone Office:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="telephoneoffice" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="telephoneoffice" /></td>
                                <td><label for="mob">Mob:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="Mob" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="mob" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="emailaddress">Email Address:</label></td>   
                                <td><input type="text" id="emailaddress" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="emailaddress" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="academicqualification">Academic Qualification:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="academicqualification" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="academicqualification" /></td>              
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="experience">Experience Teaching / Industry:</label></td>    
                                <td><input type="text" id="experience" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="experience" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="titleofpaper">Title of Paper(s)</label></td>
                                <td><textarea id="titleofpaper" tabindex="3" name="titleofpaper" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="participationas">Participation as:</label></td> 
                                <td><input type="text" id="participationas" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="participationas" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td><label for="participationas">Participation as:</label></td>
                                <td><select>
                                    <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
                                    <option value="research">Research Scholar</option>
                                    <option value="under">Under Graduate Student</option>
                                    <option value="industrial">Industrial Participant</option>
                                    <option value="participant">Participant Outside India</option>
                                </select></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr align="center">
                                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" /></td>
                                </tr>


                    </table>
                </form>

            </div><!-- end #content -->

            <?php get_footer(); ?>  **Line 142 this**
```

But it's giving me:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected $end in /wp-content/themes/academica/new-template.php on line 142

Can anyone suggest to me how can I solve this error ?

Comment: Please learn how PHP errors work and check through your code before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the `if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){` tag on line 42

Comment: But My Registration form have problem to insert record in database.can suggest me in above code what i have problem .

Comment: In wp-config.php set WP_DEBUG to true and tell me the error you get.